# Extracting ridges and peaks in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, saga

Is there a way to extract mountain ridges in QGIS? I have been trying to use the Valley and Ridge Detection SAGA tool, but it freezes for hours and I am wondering if there is a faster or alternative way.

I'm running QGIS 3.10 on a Mac.

[image: This is the info relative to my DEM]

[image: I kept the default settings because I wanted to try the tool first, but eventually I'd like to cover the DEM in its entirety]

Comment: Which data are you working with? How large ist your area? Which settings did you use on the tool?

Comment: Hi, I added two images to clarify your questions. I left the default settings. Sorry, I don't use QGIS regularly so I am unsure wether I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It took my PC around 5-6 minutes to run for approx 2000x2000 DEM. Yours is around 20 times that size - I assume the increase in time is not linear. Depending on how critical the resolution is, you could try downscaling your raster.